# Access Variables anywhere in hierarchy Java

Tags: java, variables

I want to access a variable set inside of a method from another method. I'm trying to access the `Scanner` `sc` in the method `inlet`, but the variable is not able to be resolved.

```
public class LineReader extends MaxObject {

    public LineReader() {
        declareInlets(new int[]{DataTypes.INT,DataTypes.ALL});
        declareOutlets(new int[]{DataTypes.INT,DataTypes.ALL});
    }

    public void input(String Fold.sc, Atom[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File());
        if (getInlet() == 1) {
            post("hello anything " + Fold.sc + " " + Atom.toOneString(args) + "!");
            outlet(1, s, args);
        } else {
            post("uh"); 
        }
    }

    public void inlet(int a) {
        for (int i = 0; i < startLine; i++) { 
            info = sc.readLine(); 
        }
        for (int i = startLine; i < endLine + 1; i++) {
            info = sc.readLine();
            System.out.println(info);
            post("hello integer " + a + "!");
            outlet(0, info);
        }       
    } 
}
```

Comment: Please rephrase the question, and point us to the place in your code where you're trying to do whatever it is. It's hard to understand the problem this way. Also, next time please indent the code so it will be less confusing.

Comment: This code is overly long and confusing. Can you trim it down to the essential parts?

Comment: I'm trying to access the scanner sc in the public void inlet, but the variable is not able to be resolved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you're having trouble understanding [variable scope](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0020__Language/VariableScope.htm). It would probably benefit you to spend some time learning about it.

Since your variable `sc` is declared inside the method `input`, it is only accessible there. If you want it to be accessible throughout the class, you should make it a member of the class.

Here's an example of how this works:

```
public class MyClass {
    int x = 3;

    public void method1() {
        int a = 1;
    }

    public void method2() {
        System.out.println(a); //will not work - a is not in scope
        System.out.println(x); //will work - x is accessible from all methods
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare Scanner SC out side of the in put function,

```
public class LineReader extends MaxObject {
Scanner sc;
public LineReader() {
declareInlets(new int[]{DataTypes.INT,DataTypes.ALL});
declareOutlets(new int[]{DataTypes.INT,DataTypes.ALL});
}
public void input(String Fold.sc, Atom[] args) {
    sc = new Scanner(new File());
        if (getInlet() == 1){
        post("hello anything " + Fold.sc + " " + Atom.toOneString(args) + "!");
        outlet(1, s, args);
    } else
        post("uh"); 
}
public void inlet(int a) {

for (int i = 0; i < startLine; i++) { info = sc.readLine(); }
for (int i = startLine; i < endLine + 1; i++) {
info = sc.readLine();
System.out.println(info);
post("hello integer " + a + "!");
outlet(0, info);
        }       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your scanner instance is local to input method. You need to pass the instance to the inlet method to be able to use it there.

```
public void input(String Fold.sc, Atom[] args) {
 ...
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File());
 ... 
}
public void inlet(int a, Scanner sc) {
...
    for (int i = 0; i < startLine; i++) { info = sc.readLine(); }
...
}
```